# Unable to use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the browser loads a js file, it's working with `document.getElementById("name")`.

But when I change to jQuery style, which is `$("#name")`, that particular element doesn't seem to work any more.

This is how I write my script file in the HTML (right above the closing body tag)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/form.js"></script>
</body>
```

Does anyone knows why jQuery doesn't work?

Edit:

It's just simple code, replacing all document.getElementById to $. 
But since you asked, this is the original js code that I've used:

```
function formValidation() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name"),
        email = document.getElementById("email"),
        phone = document.getElementById("phone"),
        message = document.getElementById("message"),
        nameRe = /[a-zA-Z]/,
        emailRe = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/,
        phoneRe = /[0-9]/,
        messageError = "";

    document.getElementById("frmContact").onsubmit = function () {
        messageError = "";

        // Validation for name, email and phone, using regular expression
        if (!nameRe.test(name.value)) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(name, "Invalid name");
        } else if (!emailRe.test(email.value)) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(email, "Invalid email");
        } else if (!phoneRe.test(phone.value)) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(phone, "Invalid phone");
        } else if (message.value.length <= 50) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(message, "Message must be at least 50 characters");
        }

        // form validation
        if (messageError !== "") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = messageError;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

Comment: show relevant codes that you have used, esp. the part where you implemented jQuery

Comment: Just wrap the code in DOM ready function

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you plz post relevant JS code.

Comment: @skobaljic , that shouldn't have anything to do with it, especially if the vanilla JS function worked.

Comment: `name.value` won't work than, you use jQuery object, so use `name.val()` method, `message.val()` etc. Also change stuff in `errorHighlight` function, you use jQuery objects now. If you want to access original DOM element, than you can use `name[0]` or `message[0]`.

Comment: @ctn , better you try the solution provided by skobaljic. Since the method you using right now is not jQuery function.

Comment: @skobaljic this seems to be the case. I used .val() in stead of .value. Also jQuery object doesn't seem to modify DOM the same way javascript object does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `.val()`  ex: `name.val()`  or  `$("#name").val()`

```
if (!nameRe.test(name.val())) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(name, "Invalid name");
        } else if (!emailRe.test(email.val())) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(email, "Invalid email");
        } else if (!phoneRe.test(phone.val())) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(phone, "Invalid phone");
        } else if (message.val().length <= 50) {
            messageError = errorHighlight(message, "Message must be at least 50 characters");
        }
```

Comment: also `message.val().length`

Comment: @ctn, yes, my bad. didn't spot that.

Answer (score -1):

Following how to use it as a small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>It Works!</h1>
        <div id="changethat"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            (function($,undefined){
                $('#changethat').html('Changed!');
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxamct1n/1/

Comment: Not if his form.js contains something that can get in conflict with $. Besides  it's unnecessary, do you know any disadvantages still using it to be sure?